# How to access to image property in JS using KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I am uploading and loading an image in JS.
So when I use console.log(anImage), I get an element like below.

```
  draggable: (...)
> elm: text
> image: img
    complete: (...)
    contentEditable: (...)
    crossOrigin: (...)
    currentSrc: (...)
    dataset: (...)
    decoding: (...)
    dir: (...)
    draggable: (...)
    firstChild: (...)
    firstElementChild: (...)
    height: 600
    isRootInsert: false
  name: 'pear'

console.log(anImage.name) // 'pear'
```

But my goal is I want to get the height of image properties.
So when I put 'anImage.image' it just gives me the path of image not the properties of image. How can I access to image properties to get the height? Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: Can you make a demo? Where did you get `anImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to load an image and check the dimensions using Javascript. Note however that the process of loading an image is asynchronous, meaning your JS code could execute 'before' the image is accessed from the server and pulled across the web to the client where the JS is running. This means you have to wait or 'listen' until the load completion event fires on the image object before you look at its dimensions.

In plain Javascript you could use a simple process as here:

```js
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
    }
    img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

The trick here is settings the img.onload listener so that the function it declares is executed for you when the image 'arrives' at the client where the JS code is executing.

When you use images in Konva you must follow the same pattern. The Konvajs documentation has a [simple example of image loading using onload()](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Image.html)

Misunderstanding the async nature of working with server-sourced assets is a very common tripping-point for folks who are new to it.